# Jquery Ajax displaying data in HTML not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

okay gang.

I have an ajax function (in code below). It sends data to a php file, retrieves it, and posts in a html div. 
I have two different pages, both in the same folder, that use the code. They are not open at the same time ever. One is a 'loggedout' page, and the other 'loggedin' page. The below ajax works for the 'loggedout' page but not for the 'loggedin' page. For testing purposes I made both pages identical. The ajax code is linked to the pages in a separate file. Same file for both pages. Heres the ajax:

```
function ajaxFilterCategorySearch(find,param1) {
    $.ajax ({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "../php/categorySearch.php",
        data:{ find : find, param1 : param1} ,
        success: function(data) { 
            $('#'+param1).html(data);   
        }
    }); 
}
```

I tested it so it alerts the following:

1)data

2)param1

It alerts both of these things correctly. This means that it IS working. It is getting the right data and it is getting the right div (param1) to put the data in.
Remember it works for an identical page in the same folder also. Why is not working for this one page and is for the other. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any console errors that you could post?

Comment: Are you sur all link to the two page are ok? exemple page1.html is link to jquery1.html but page2.html is intended to be link to jquery1.html but a mistake was made in the path to include that file?

Comment: Press F-12, open the debugger. Look for errors.

Comment: Can you post the code that calls `ajaxFilterCategorySearch(find,param1)`, both for the page that works and the one that does not?

Comment: Here is a JSFiddle with your code (slightly modified for jsfiddle's sake) working: http://jsfiddle.net/fAQjn/.  If in your JavaScript console you don't see the ajax get firing then your problem is with how you invoke this function.  If event fires but you don't see any effect it could be your selector in the success callback

Answer (score 0):

as Jnatalzia and Diodeus already suggested it's crucial to use debugger when coding :) so if you do not use chrome instal [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and see if there are any errors! if you find any paste those here so we can take a look.